# Ionic cordova Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to build my ionic app and get the following error.

```
Error: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ionic/newBuild/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/NavUtils$NavUtilsImpl;
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Did you get an answer? I'm facing similar issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be the document viewer plugin I removed this and the  support-v4.jar which this plugin depended on and is now fixed.